# Getting the new coordinates of bounding box and object in it after rotating an image,, given the coordinates in COCO format

Tags: python, json, opencv, image-processing, object-detection

I have a json file which has the coordinates of objects in bounding box(bbox) and bbox co-ordinates as well in COCO format. The bounding box dimensions are top left x, y points, then width and height. The object inside the bounding box is a polygon of irregular shape and its points are saved in json file.
As per the comment I included a lookalike image and it's points from a Jason file. Points are given to illustrate as they do not represent original points.
[image]
{
"info": {
"year": 2021,
"version": "1.0",
"description": "",
"contributor": "",
"url": "",
"date_created": "Wed Jun 23 10:56:50 2021"
},
"licenses": [],
"images": [
{
"id": 1,
"width": 576,
"height": 752,
"file_name": "/data/files/training-files/tmp/images/img1.JPG",
"license": 0,
"flickr_url": "http://00.00.00.00:0000/data/files_1/FINAL/img1.JPG",
"coco_url": "http://00.00.00.00:0000/data/files/FINAL/img1.JPG",
"date_captured": ""
}
],
"categories": [
{
"supercategory": "class",
"id": 1,
"name": "get1"
},
{
"supercategory": "class",
"id": 2,
"name": "get2"
},
{
"supercategory": "class",
"id": 3,
"name": "get3"
},
{
"supercategory": "class",
"id": 4,
"name": "get4"
},
{
"supercategory": "class",
"id": 5,
"name": "get5"
}
],
"annotations": [
{
"segmentation": [
[
435,
540,
431,
539,
426,
537,
420,
536,
417,
535,
421
]
],
"area": 3654,
"bbox": [
416,
453,
42,
87
],
"iscrowd": 0,
"id": 1,
"image_id": 1,
"category_id": 3
}
]
}

The objective is 1.To lay the bounding box and contours on the original image based on these co-ordinates. 2.To rotate the image 90 degrees and get the new bbox and segmentation coordinates. 3. To resize the original dimensions and get the new coordinates of bbox and segments(because not all the image files are of the same size.) I am using opencv and python.
I may also have many instances in the image and many images of unequal sizes.

I met the first objective,
To draw the contours and bounding box,

```
 pts=np.array((segmentation points),dtype=np.int32)
 pts=pts.reshape((-1,1,2))
 thickness=4
 img_poly=cv2.polylines(org_image, pts, True, (255,0,0), thickness)
bbox=[416,453,42,87]
xmin = bbox[0]
ymin = bbox[1]
xmax = xmin + bbox[2]
ymax = ymin + bbox[3]

start_point = (xmin, ymin) 
end_point = (xmax, ymax) 

# Blue color in BGR 
color = (255, 0, 0) 

# Line thickness of 3 pixels 
thickness = 3

image_2 = cv2.rectangle(img_poly, start_point, end_point, color, 
thickness) 

plt.imshow(image_2)
plt.show()
```

Some pointers on achieving the above objectives are most appreciated.

Comment: Sharing your image and corresponding JSON would be a good start.

Comment: Python supports JSON natively. See https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html